# Ruby: How can I have a Hash take multiple keys?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm taking 5 strings (protocol, source IP and port, destination IP and port) and using them to store some values in a hash. The problem is that if the IPs or ports are switched between source and destination, the key is supposed to be the same.

If I was doing this in C#/Java/whatever I'd have to create a new class and overwrite the hashcode()/equals() methods, but that seems error prone from the little I've read about it and I was wondering if there would be a better alternative here.

Comment: This question is worded confusingly. If I understand you correctly, it's not that you want a hash to have "multiple keys" (which is trivial: `{:a => "foo", :b => "bar"}`). It's that you want two hashes with identical keys but different values to still compare as equal under certain circumstances. Is that right?

Comment: Well, basically, I want hash["john doe"] to be equal to hash["doe john"]. Except since I have 5 keys, it's a bit more complex than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am directly copying a paragraph from *Programming Ruby 1.9*:

> Hash keys must respond to the message `hash` by returning a hash code, and the hash code for a given key must not change.  The keys used in hashes must also be comparable using `eql?`. If `eql?` returns `true` for two keys, then those keys must also have the same hash code. This means that certain classes (such as `Array` and `Hash`) can't conveniently be used as keys, because their hash values can change based on their contents.

So you might generate your hash as something like `["#{source_ip} #{source_port}", "#{dest_ip} #{dest_port}", protocol.to_s].sort.join.hash` such that the result will be identical when the source and destination are switched.

For example:

```
source_ip = "1.2.3.4"
source_port = 1234

dest_ip = "5.6.7.8"
dest_port = 5678

protocol = "http"

def make_hash(s_ip, s_port, d_ip, d_port, proto)
    ["#{s_ip} #{s_port}", "#{d_ip} #{d_port}", proto.to_s].sort.join.hash
end

puts make_hash(source_ip, source_port, dest_ip, dest_port, protocol)
puts make_hash(dest_ip, dest_port, source_ip, source_port, protocol)
```

This will output the same hash even though the arguments are in a different order between the two calls.  Correctly encapsulating this functionality into a class is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm using strings, and that only mentions arrays and hashes. Though I'm new to Ruby. Are strings arrays? Or is it something else I'm missing?

Comment: Th code fragment `["#{source_ip} #{source_port}", "#{dest_ip} #{dest_port}", protocol.to_s].sort.join` creates a temporary array, then sorts it (which allows source and dest to be swapped), then `join`s it into a string.  Finally calling `hash` on that string should suffice for use in a hash.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean...

```
irb(main):001:0> traffic = []
=> []
irb(main):002:0> traffic << {:src_ip => "10.0.0.1", :src_port => "9999", :dst_ip => "172.16.1.1", :dst_port => 80, :protocol => "tcp"}
=> [{:protocol=>"tcp", :src_ip=>"10.0.0.1", :src_port=>"9999", :dst_ip=>"172.16.1.1", :dst_port=>80}]
irb(main):003:0> traffic << {:src_ip => "10.0.0.2", :src_port => "9999", :dst_ip => "172.16.1.1", :dst_port => 80, :protocol => "tcp"}
=> [{:protocol=>"tcp", :src_ip=>"10.0.0.1", :src_port=>"9999", :dst_ip=>"172.16.1.1", :dst_port=>80}, {:protocol=>"tcp", :src_ip=>"10.0.0.2", :src_port=>"9999", :dst_ip=>"172.16.1.1", :dst_port=>80}]
```

The next, somewhat related, question is how to store the IP. You probably want to use the [IPAddr](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IPAddr.html) object instead of just a string so you can sort the results more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
def create_hash(prot, s_ip, s_port, d_ip, d_port, value, x = nil)
  if x
    x[prot] = {s_ip => {s_port => {d_ip => {d_port => value}}}}
  else
    {prot => {s_ip => {s_port => {d_ip => {d_port => value}}}}}
  end
end

# Create a value
h = create_hash('www', '1.2.4.5', '4322', '4.5.6.7', '80', "Some WWW value")

# Add another value
create_hash('https', '1.2.4.5', '4562', '4.5.6.7', '443', "Some HTTPS value", h)

# Retrieve the values
puts h['www']['1.2.4.5']['4322']['4.5.6.7']['80']
puts h['https']['1.2.4.5']['4562']['4.5.6.7']['443']
```